# "the better" vs "the best" of two players

Tags: phrases, articles, definite-articles, comparisons

I used the book "Grammar and Style" and one example confused me:

> He was the better/ best of two players.

The answer was ***the better*** but learners wonder how is it true since we use *best* after the definite article, *the*.

Was the answer given above correct?

Comment: We might use *the best* but we also use *the better*. *The better of the two strikers is injured*.

Comment: The best can be used to convey the idea that one player is much better than the other.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that a superlative, when it pre-modifies a noun attributively, is usually preceded by the definite article, as in *He was the best player in the team*. It is also true that the comparative is often preceded by the indefinite article, as in *He was a better player after he had extra coaching*. But where one player is being compared with another, the definite article is required, as in *He was the better of the two players*. You cannot say that one player is the best when only two are being compared.

Comment: "The best of two players" or "The best of two choices" are wrong? How about three?

Comment: -1 too pedantic and not indicative of how language is used, i.e, ***May the best man win*** said to the *two* boxers before they fight.

Answer (score 0):

English speakers got used to the idea of using "better" in place of "best" when comparing two elements (probably because there are idioms where "the" accompanies "better, like The more the better), and hence it has become common use.

But, as in every other existing language in the world, a comparative is a comparative (something is better THAN something else) and a superlative is a superlative (something is THE best), either when it's two or a thousands of elements. the confusion probably arises from the fact that in order to compare we use only two objects, and so it feels more normal to transfer that term to a sentence where the superlative is between just two.

But as per origin of the grammar element, although now changed and accepted, is substantially wrong.

Comment: "as in every other existing language in the world" - you may be surprised: languages are weird.

Comment: Sorry, what is "substantially wrong"? Your last sentence doesn't make sense.